# How to update array when navigating from modal to page in Ionic app?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here are the `Conversation` & `Message` models I am using in my Ionic 5 / Angular app:

```
export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        public timestamp: string
    ) { }
}

export class Conversation {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        public messages: Message[]
    ) { }
}
```

In my `Create-Conversation` modal, I'm creating a `Conversation` by calling a method in my `Conversation-Service`:

```
 onSendMessage() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.conversationsService.addConversation(this.mechanicToContact.id, this.form.value.message);
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss(null, 'cancel');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('conversation-list');
  }
```

Then I want the user to navigate to the `conversation-list` page where they should see a list of all existing conversations **(including the newly added one)**

Here is the code in my `Conversation-Service`:

```
addConversation(mechanicId: string, message: string) {

    const newConversation = new Conversation(
      Math.random().toString(),
      this.authService.userId,
      mechanicId,
      [this.createMessage(message)]
    );
    this._conversations.push(newConversation);
    console.log(this._conversations);
  }

  private createMessage(message: string): Message {
    return {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      text: message,
      userId: this.authService.userId,
      timestamp: Date.now().toString()
    };
  }
```

When I run this code, I am console logging `_conversations` & seeing the additional `Conversation` being pushed successfully.

However, when the user is navigated to `Conversation-Detail` only the previously existing `Conversation`'s are displayed.

Can someone please tell me how I can display the latest `Conversation` objects when navigating from `Create-Conversation` to `Conversation-Detail`?

Here is the code in my `Conversation-Detail` page:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadedConversations = this.conversationsService.conversations;
    console.log(this.loadedConversations);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding the below function to ``Conversation-List:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.loadedConversations = this.conversationsService.conversations;
}
```